# Controller Variable not Showing up in Query Builder Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am encountering a strange issue in Laravel.

The below is an index function in one of my controllers.

```
public function index($merchant_url_text)
{
    //
    $deals = DB::table('tbl_deal')
            -> join ('tbl_merchant', 'tbl_deal.merchant_id', '=', 'tbl_merchant.merchant_id')
            -> where ('merchant_url_text', $merchant_url_text) -> toSql();
    //return $merchant_url_text.$deal_id;
            dd($deals);
            //return $merchant_url_text;
}
```

As you can see I am passing merchant_url_text from route.

```
Route::get('/testroute/{merchant_url_text}', ['uses' =>'dealsVisibleController@index']);
```

When I am trying to debug the query by printing it, I am getting

```
"select * from `tbl_deal` inner join `tbl_merchant` on `tbl_deal`.`merchant_id` = `tbl_merchant`.`merchant_id` where `merchant_url_text` = ?"
```

This means that the query builder is not reading the $merchant_url_text variable. However, when I return just that variable, it is being printed.

Just can't figure out why the query builder is not able to include the $merchant_url_text variable in the query when it is available in the index function.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that your code is correct. The SQL output function `toSql()` does not show the values of variables and only prints out a `?` for security reasons.

Comment: thanks. You were right. Had some issue with angular view that was not displaying data. the query was working though.

Answer (score 1):

You may access all your queries by using

`$queries = DB::getQueryLog();`

**It is also printing the query parameters as array**.

To get the last query:

`dd(end($queries));`

To disable the log:

`DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();`

See the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#query-logging) for further information.