# Is it possible to do relationship eager loading in a DB query with laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, relationship

I wondered if it was possible to create a DB query and build into that query a similar approach to the way eager loading works with laravel eloquent.

I have a query in my controller that gets offers with their relationship which is this point is days and venue. My models are as follows:

Day model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Day extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the offer days for the offer.
     */

    protected $fillable = ['start_time','end_time'];

    public function offers()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Offer');
    }
}
```

My offer model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

use DB;

class Offer extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'offers';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden  = ['map_location', 'regular', 'name'];
    protected $fillable = ['id','venue_id','type_id','day', 'venue_address','is_featured','repeater_days','image', 'venue_description', 'offer_headline','offer_subheader','offer_terms','venue_phone_number','venue_website', 'venue_name', 'venue_headline','venue_description','venue_latitude','venue_longitude','offer_when','offer_end_time','offer_start_time','offer_start_date','offer_end_date','featured_date','current_time','current_date'];
    public static $rules = array(
        'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,bmp,gif,svg'
    );
    protected $casts = [
        'is_featured' => 'boolean',
        'is_regular' => 'boolean',
        'offer_when' => 'array'
    ];
    /**
     * Get the offers for the offer.
    */
    public function days()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Day','day_offer', 'offer_id', 'day_id');
    }

    public function types()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Type', 'offer_type');
    }

    public function venue()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Venue', 'offer_venue', 'offer_id', 'venue_id');
    }


}
```

My venue model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Venue extends Model
{
    //
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'venues';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = ['id','address','description','phone_number','website','name', 'headline','lat','lng','days'];

    public static $rules = array(
        'name' => ''
    );

    protected $casts = [
        'lat' => 'float(10,8)',
        'lng' => 'float(11,8)'
    ];

    public function offers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Offer','offer_venue');
    }

}
```

I want to get each relationship and load the results into the query so that i have the main object and the relationships like so:

[image]

The problem with this is it looks great and works and the eloquent is so simple but I cannot do further more complex things on it like:

"Getting the distance from the venue and loading the offers based on the distance of the venue with a haversine formula I used."

This would require a query like so and in an ideal world the distance would be in the main returned offer object on every offer not within the venue[] relationship:

```
$radius = '10000';
$query->having('distance', '<', $radius);
$query->orderBy('distance', 'desc');
```

Where i am becoming stuck is that I do not know how to write the proper DB query to do exactly what you see in the image above which is what I want and eventually I can then do the "offers based on the location" and order them.

I have started with the eloquent query below:

```
public function indexAll(Offer $offer)
    {

        $mytime = Carbon::now('Europe/London');
        $time = $mytime->format('H:i');
        $timeInt = $this->hourMinToInteger($time);
        $today = $mytime->format('m/d/Y');
        $day = strtolower($mytime->format('l'));
        $tomorrow = strtolower(Carbon::now()->addDay(1)->format('l'));

        // $offers = Offer::all();
        //$haversine = DB::raw('3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( $offer ) ) * cos( radians( $offer ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( $offer ) ) ) as distance');
        $offersWithDays = Offer::with([
                'days' => function($allDays){
                    $allDays->select('id','day');
                },
                'venue' => function($query){
                    $query->select('lat','lng','address','description','phone_number','website','name', 'headline')
                        ->addSelect(DB::raw('3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) as distance')
                    );
                }
            ])
            ->get();

        $response = [
            'now' => [],
            'later' => [],
            'tomorrow' => [],
            'featured' => []
        ];

        // validOffers are all offers that fall within this stuff
        foreach ($offersWithDays as $offerAll) {
            $relation = $offerAll->days()->get();
            $relationVenues = $offerAll->venue();
            //var_dump($relation);
            $theDays = array();
            foreach ($relation as $theDay) {
              $theDayObj = $theDay->day;
              array_push($theDays,$theDayObj);
            }
            extract($theDays);

            if ($offerAll->is_featured) {
                $response['featured'][] = $offerAll;
            }
            if (in_array($day,$theDays) && $offerAll->offer_start_time < $time) {
                $response['now'][] = $offerAll;
            }
            if (in_array($day,$theDays) && $offerAll->offer_start_time > $time) {
                $response['later'][] = $offerAll;
            }
            if (in_array($tomorrow,$theDays)) {
                $response['tomorrow'][] = $offerAll;
            }
        }
        return $response;
    }
```

What I would like to know is that the code I have created in eloquent is as easily done with a normal DB query with joins and selects in it?

Comment: Did you check the query log to see what query is created? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279635/controller-variable-not-showing-up-in-query-builder-laravel/34281344#34281344

Comment: where would that go Daenu

Comment: I just meant that with the log you may see the created query and then rebuild it, but BTW I wonder why one would do that

Comment: well its best for developing it as you go so you can see the process I know. Just tried DB::getQueryLog() and it returns false i am on laravel 5.1